# Dymanimcally add links in main menu (e.g. last 4 nodes)

Tags: views, routes, blocks

I have main navigation menu with root menu items. A request is that one of those have links to latest 4 nodes of a certain content type. So for example if I have a structure similar to this:

-Parent item:

- child item 4
- child item 3
- child item 2
- child item 1

(All child items are all of the same content type, for example Article)

When a user adds a new node of the content type Article, the structure should be the following:

-Parent item:

- child item 5
- child item 4
- child item 3
- child item 2

All I can think of is to use Views to make a list of linked titles in a block and then to attach the block to the menu (i'm using TB Mega Menu which allows this). 
The solely problem with this approach is that I then don't have trail of active menu items in menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Make the URLs static; have the content of those URLs change**

You were on the right track with views. But don't use it to create a block with the links, use it to create a page that displays the full rendered entity of the last node of your content type. You can give it a URL like `/latest-article`.

You could get fancy and use contextual arguments to display the 2nd, 3rd, ... offsets (e.g. `/latest-article/%`) or you could just add four more displays to the view, each with the offset bumped up by one.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the you can choose what menu and what parent should those links go . That way, all the new links should appear where you wish.

[image: menu settings for a given content type]

Then, using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Menu Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_rules) you can make disappear the oldest menu link when you add a new one.